# calculating the fraction with struct in c

Tags: c, struct

im trying to calculate the fraction with structs, the compiler says that initializer list cannot be converted, whats actually the issue? here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct fraction{ 
    int z = 0; 
    int n = 1;
};
struct fraction addition(struct fraction b1, struct fraction b2) {
    struct fraction result;
    result.z = b1.z*b2.n + b2.z*b1.n;
    result.n = b1.n*b2.n;

    return result;
    }

void Print(struct fraction b) { 
    printf("%d/%d\n", b.z, b.n);

}
int main() {
    int i;
    struct fraction b1 = { 1,1 }, b2 = { 1,2 };
    try {
        for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { 

        Print(addition(b1, b2));

    }
}
    catch (int exception) {
        printf("Program closed!");
    }
}
```

the for loop by the way is harmonic series but im not done with it yet. thanks for help in advance

Comment: `int z = 0;  int n = 1;` --> `int z;  int n;`.

Comment: C or C++?  The title says "C", the tags say "C++".

Comment: @Sparkm4n I removed your C tag. Because your code is clearly C++ not C. But then I noticed your title says C. Please clarify which language you are using. They are not the same and the answer may be different for each language.

Comment: actually its c but my code is mixed with c++

Comment: EDIT: the next problem is the harmonic series in the for loop, i already improved the code and it works fine but it prints out random numbers the for loop here:                                                                                                       for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { 
  struct fraction b1 = {b1.z, b1.n }, b2 = { i, 1 };
  Print(addition(b1, b2));

Comment: all right already solved: for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
   fraction b1 = {}, b2 = { 1, i };
    result = addition(result,b2);
    printf("%d/%d\n", result.z, result.n);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove assigned values from struct (for C++11 and below):

```
struct fraction{
    int z;
    int n;
};
```

Now it compiles fine, tested with g++ 5.2.1 (should get the job done for other compilers too).

When I added option `-std=c++14` your code compiled just fine without any changes.

Answer (score 3):

When you use C++, you don't need to use `struct fraction`. You can but you don't need to. You can use just `fraction`.

Coming to the problematic line:

```
struct fraction b1 = { 1,1 }, b2 = { 1,2 };
```

You can use:

```
fraction b1{ 1,1 };
fraction b2{ 1,2 };
```

or

```
fraction b1 = fraction{ 1,1 }, b2 = fraction{ 1,2 };
```

Answer (score 1):

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
I read that user defined constructors will stop you from initializing with braces and, I guess, initializing your variables in the struct will act like an user defined constructor.

> no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)

so writing just :

```
struct fraction{
    int z; 
    int n; 
};
```

should solve the problem

Comment: "initializing variables in the struct" is covered by the bullet point about default member initializers on that cppreference page.

Answer (score 1):

here is my idea how you could solve the problem

```
#include "stdafx.h" 

int euclid( int a, int b );

struct fraction {
    int z;
    int n;
};

typedef struct fraction Bruch;

Bruch add( Bruch b1, Bruch b2 ) {
    Bruch r;
    r.z = b1.z * b2.n + b2.z * b1.n;
    r.n  = b1.n * b2.n;
    return r;
}

void print( Bruch b ) {
    printf("%d / %d \n", b.z, b.n );
}


void test() {
    Bruch eins = {1,1};
    Bruch halb = {1,2};

    printf(" ---------------- structure---------------- \n" );
    Bruch sum = add( eins, halb );
    print(sum);

    sum.z = 0;
    sum.n = 1;

    Bruch summand = {1,1};

    for( int n=1; n<=6; ++n ) {
        summand.nenner = n;
        sum = add( sum, summand );
        print(sum);
    }
}
```